# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type in Open API 3

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I have a @RestController with such method

```
@RestController
public MyController {

@Operation(summary = "Some text", description = "Some text again"
@GetMapping("/route")
public MyClassResponse getSomething(
@Parameter(name = "My request", description = "My request") MyRequest request
) {

    // to do smth

    return response
}
```

where MyRequest is

```
public class MyRequest {

private int param1;

private String param2;

private MyClass param3;

}
```

and MyClass looks like

```
public class MyClass {

private int clazzParam1;
private int clazzParam2;
}
```

First of all, Swagger shows parameter MyRequest like body

```
{
"param1" : 0;
"param2" : "string",
"param3" : {
    "clazzParam1" : 0,
    "clazzParam2" : 0
    }
}
```

but I would like to see every parameter[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypHjO.png)

Second when I try make request, I get this curl

http://localhost:8080/route?param1=0&param2=string&param3=clazzParam1,0,clazzParam2,0

instead

http://localhost:8080/route?param1=0&param2=string&param3.clazzParam1=0&param3.clazzParam2=0

Therefore response contain next failure 
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'MyClass' for property 'param3'.

How should I use annotations to get what I want? 
For various reasons I can't use .yaml description. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@ParameterObject is answer. It unpacking object to parameters in Swagger UI